# iOS : ZGParallelView pull to full screen.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

ZGParallelView, I am facing one problem to do with this control.
I want to do the if the user pull down the image view comes to full screen and if user swipe up to normal screen. This idea I am getting from Expedia app please look on this the Hotel full screen mode do the exactly what I am trying to explain.

https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGParallelView

If anyone have any idea to do the same feature then please share me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I am pull down and pull up in this control ZGParallelView, Image is not comes in full screen. please check the Expedia app.

Comment: Anyone have any idea to do the same ???